# Azure Maps requests monitoring

Tags: azure, azure-maps

Does anybody knows, what metric is shown in Azure Maps usage diagrams?
[This is what diagram looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1gu8.png), and number of request in the charts significantly differs from my traffic amounts. It seems like 10-15 requests in the graph per each visitor on the site.
I suppose that charts showing amount of map-tiles loaded, where each tile load is considered as a request.

**Update**

The question is about using [JavaScript maps control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-map-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map loads in map control is tracked as Map tile API requests where each API request renders one tile. On Azure portal on the Azure maps usage page you can click on "Apply splitting" button and group the usage by "API name" to confirm your assumption.

Comment: Thank you for pointing at 'Splitting' option. Now it is a bit clearer. I see a number of GetTile requests and another two: GetSearchFuzzy and GetCopyrightCaption. But I trying to figure out the billing mechanism. Will it bill me for each 15 tile requests as 1 transaction (as mentioned at [Pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/azure-maps/)) and all other requests, or all requests will be devided by 15?

Comment: Your first interpretation is correct. It will bill you for each 15 tile requests as 1 transaction and all other requests.

Comment: Thank you Jingjing! Can you please clarify one more thing. I just put the map on the web-page, without any search capabilities, just showing map at certain location. So why there are so many GetSearchFuzzy requests? Is it appears when user scrolling or moving map?

Comment: Those search queries are for accessibility information. Specifically those requests are for the current colloquial region name for the center of the map.  We are looking into allowing customers to disable the accessibility feature.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an accurate answer without more context but `usage` (along with `availability`) itself is the metric in the graph. You can also apply *filters* on the graph based on `API Names`, `API categories`, `Response codes` etc. and it'll show you the `count` of requests for that specific api(s). I'm guessing you might be using the [Get Map Tile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/render/getmaptile) in which case each tile load is a separate request and will be counted as such on the dashboard.

If that doesn't answer you question please add more context as to what api(s) are you using and i can try and answer more accurately.

Comment: Thank you, Michael for reply! I'm using [JavaScript map control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-map-control), and the question is about web front-end maps.